# EF4 - is it possible to see which ObjectContext is tracking a particular Entity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4, automapper, entities, objectcontext

EDIT: I'd like to get a definitive answer on whether or not it's possible to determine which ObjectContext is tracking which Entities. Is there a particular property that says "Entity *x* belongs to this context?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have references to all possible `ObjectContext` instances, you can determine to which one a given entity instance is attached to by calling their [.ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry(Object, out ObjectStateEntry)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679461.aspx) methods - the right one will return true. If you don't, there is no straightforward public API to get from an entity instance to an ObjectContext instance. If the entity has relationships and implements [IEntityWithRelationships](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.dataclasses.ientitywithrelationships.aspx), you can retrieve its [RelationshipManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.dataclasses.ientitywithrelationships.relationshipmanager.aspx), ask it to get any related end (aka "navigation property") with [GetAllRelatedEnds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.dataclasses.relationshipmanager.getallrelatedends.aspx), ask the related end to create a query with [CreateSourceQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.dataclasses.irelatedend.createsourcequery.aspx), cast it to an [ObjectQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.objectquery.aspx) and finally retrieve the [.Context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectquery.context.aspx). You don't have to do all this if you're willing to use reflection to access internal members of Entity Framework classes, but still the best you can get from an instance of an entity without relationships is an `ObjectStateManager`, not `ObjectContext`. Better yet, if you require to access the `ObjectContext` from an entity instance, you can use a custom entity base class (with custom code generation template or otherwise) with an `ObjectContext` property which you can populate and clear in the event handler for [ObjectStateManagerChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectstatemanager.objectstatemanagerchanged.aspx).

Comment: Just wanted to say that TryGetObjectStateEntry() helped me solve my problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't necessarily answer your question but its important for a developer to understand the contexts for which they are instantiating and one method is to realize the "UnitOfWork".  For each unit of work there exists a single context and for that unit of work to perform the specific task at hand (e.g. save form data).  Using the "UnitOfWork" pattern, it then receives Id's for dependent objects (or the object itself for the Id), retrieves the objects, creates new objects, wires up dependent and new objects then saves changes.  Then for the code block calling the unit of work to notify other areas of code for which changes have been made via messaging.  But since you are stateless the messaging convention would not directly apply.

The second is, I hardly use AutoMapper or alike and instead use POCO with Code First.  Using this convention I now use my POCO objects as by business objects which get populated by the data layer (EF) where my configurations now occur in the DbContext (UnitOfWork) OnModelCreating method.  Removing the entire mapping process reduces a fair amount of code and complexity.  So my recommendation is to look at your design and ensure there are clear cut patterns for which you manage/seperate data access.

With all that said, mappers are great for web services.  The purpose is to minimize the amount of data sent and received through the request and response processing.  For example if all the caller wants is the first and last name therefore it doesn't make sense to send the entire profile.

Comment: Good general advice.  Not sure how it helps my particular problem, but good advice nonetheless.  I'm all but convinced it's some sort of scope issue with AutoMapper as, like I said in the topic I linked to, my own static mapper works just fine with the same code.  The only difference is that I wrote it all, so there's no underlying code coming into play.

Comment: Yah, sorry to not directly answer your question.  Well not at all but my hope is to illustrate an approach to avoid data management issues and simplifying code.